# How to calculate the CRS for the celestial sphere?

Tags: coordinate-system, r

### Context

I am working on a [R package](https://github.com/benyamindsmith/starBliss) that allows users to make custom star maps which displays the night sky for a given location and time. The package aims to replicate the product offered by [MapsForMoments](https://mapsformoments.co.uk/9-star-map?step=design).

### The Question

**TL;DR:** *How do you calculate the rotation of the celestial sphere for a given location and date?*

The code I have is:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygeocoder)
library(sf)
library(s2)
library(grid)
library(lubridate)
library(withr)

plot_starmap <- function(location,
                         date = today(),
                         style = c('black', 'green'),
                         line1_text = location,
                         line2_text = format(as.Date(date), "%B %d, %Y"),
                         line3_text=TRUE){

  # Using match.arg to avoid spelling errors with the argument specification
  style <- match.arg(style)
  # Cleaning up date arg
  date<- as.Date(date)

  # Formatted date
  dt<- lubridate::ymd(date)


  # Extract relevant latitude and longitude.

  # Latitude is dependent on location
  suppressMessages(
    capture.output(
      gocodeData <-  tibble(singlelineaddress = location) %>%
                     geocode(address=singlelineaddress,method = 'arcgis')
    )
  )

  lat <- gocodeData %>% .[["lat"]]
  # longitude for line3_text
  lon_map <-gocodeData %>%  .[["long"]]

  if(line3_text==TRUE){
    line3_text <- paste0(abs(round(lat,4)), "° ", ifelse(lat > 0, "N", "S"), ", ",
                         abs(round(lon_map,4)), "° ", ifelse(lon_map > 0, "E", "W")
    )
  }
  ref_date <- paste0(year(dt),"01","01",sep="-") %>% ydm()
  # Resulting longitude
  lon <- (-as.numeric(difftime(ref_date,dt, units="days"))/365)*360 %>% round(4)

  # The CRS

  projString <- paste0("+proj=laea +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=",lon, " +lat_0=", lat)


  # Data Transformation
  flip <- matrix(c(-1, 0, 0, 1), 2, 2)

  hemisphere_1 <- s2::s2_buffer_cells(
    s2::as_s2_geography(paste0("POINT(", lon, " ", lat, ")")),
    distance = 1e7,
    max_cells = 5000)

  hemisphere_2 <- st_sfc(st_point(c(lon, lat)), crs = 4326) %>%
    st_buffer(dist = 1e7) %>%
    st_transform(crs = projString)

  # Reading Data
  invisible(
    capture.output(
      constellation_lines_sf <- invisible(st_read(system.file("data", "constellations.lines.json", package = "starBliss"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) %>%
        st_wrap_dateline(options = c("WRAPDATELINE=YES", "DATELINEOFFSET=360")) %>%
        # Use s2 for the cut
        st_as_s2() %>%
        s2::s2_intersection(hemisphere_1) %>%
        # Back to sf
        st_as_sf() %>%
        st_transform(crs = projString) %>%
        filter(!is.na(st_is_valid(.))) %>%
        mutate(geometry = geometry * flip) %>%
        # Filter if empty, since the cut can produce empty geometries
        filter(!st_is_empty(.))
    )
  )


  st_crs(constellation_lines_sf) <- projString

  # Reading Data
  withr::with_options(list(warn=-1),
  invisible(
    capture.output(
      stars_sf <- st_read(system.file("data", "stars.6.json", package = "starBliss"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
        st_transform(crs = projString) %>%
        st_intersection(hemisphere_2) %>%
        mutate(geometry = geometry * flip)
    )
  )
)
  st_crs(stars_sf) <- projString


  # Setting parameters to update map
  if(style=="black"){
    fillVal <-  '#191d29'
    colVal <- '#191d29'
    colorVal <- "white"
    majorGridCol <-"grey35"
    minorGridCol <- "grey20"
  }
  if(style == "green"){
    fillVal <-  '#164B58'
    colVal <- '#164B58'
    colorVal <- "white"
    majorGridCol <-"#FEFEFE"
    minorGridCol <- "#FEFEFE"
  }
  # Creating the frame
  mask <- polygonGrob(x = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
                            0.5 + 0.46 * cos(seq(0, 2 *pi, len = 100))),
                      y =  c(0.5, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5,
                             0.5 + 0.46 * sin(seq(0, 2*pi, len = 100))),
                      gp = gpar(fill = fillVal, col = colVal))

  p <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = stars_sf, aes(size = -exp(mag), alpha = -exp(mag)),
            color = colorVal)+
    geom_sf(data = constellation_lines_sf, color = colorVal,
            size = 0.5) +
    annotation_custom(circleGrob(r = 0.46,
                                 gp = gpar(col = colorVal, lwd = 10, fill = NA))) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 90, 15)) +
    scale_size_continuous(range = c(0, 2)) +
    annotation_custom(mask) +
    labs(caption = paste0(line1_text,'\n',line2_text,'\n',line3_text)) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          panel.grid.major = element_line(color = majorGridCol, linewidth = 1),
          panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = minorGridCol, linewidth = 1),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = fillVal, color = colVal),
          plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20),
          plot.caption = element_text(color = colorVal, hjust = 0.5,
                                      face = 2, size = 20,
                                      margin = margin(150, 20, 20, 20),
          ))


  return(p)
}
```

This code seems to work well for North America, however recently someone pointed out that it doesn't work for [Riyadh, Saudi Arabia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riyadh).

For February 14th 2023, the map produced my MapsForMoments is:

[image]

However, the visual produced by the code above is:

```r
p<-plot_starmap( "Riyadh, Saudi Arabia",
              date="2023-02-14")

ggsave('saudi.jpg', plot = p, width = unit(10, 'in'), height = unit(15, 'in'))
```

[image]

### A more focused look

The present approach that I have for calculating the CRS in the code above is the following:

```r
 gocodeData <-  tibble(singlelineaddress = location) %>%
                     geocode(address=singlelineaddress,method = 'arcgis')
# Cleaning up date arg
date<- as.Date(date)

# Formatted date
dt<- lubridate::ymd(date)

lat <- gocodeData %>% .[["lat"]]


ref_date <- paste0(year(dt),"01","01",sep="-") %>% ydm()
# Resulting longitude
lon <- (-as.numeric(difftime(ref_date,dt, units="days"))/365)*360 %>% round(4)

# The CRS

projString <- paste0("+proj=laea +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=",lon, " +lat_0=", lat)
```

I believe the issue is with the longitude value more than the latitude.

Comment: Hmmm there's a lot to unpick in your code. I assume somewhere it considers that you want a view looking from the centre of a sphere outwards, which is opposite to conventional cartography. Is that what the "flip" does? You should maybe try and break it up into testable functions, I assume a key part of this is taking the viewer's lat-long and time and working out the overhead point "lat-long" on the celestial sphere? There should be a function then that just does that (no graphics etc) for testing. A monolithic structure like this is difficult.

Comment: @Spacedman We need a way to flip the longitude co-ordinates to make it appear that we are looking up at a celestial sphere rather than down on one. "flip" does the affine transformation to accomidate that.

Comment: Hi Bensstats, I needed to work a lot on that for this blog post:  https://dieghernan.github.io/202301_star-map-R/ See the custom function `get_mst()` . Also Maps for moments assumes the exact time at 22:00 UTC regardless of the time zone of your coordinates (that is not correct). Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this would be accepted as a proper answer. Here is the code, the full explanation is on [this long post](https://dieghernan.github.io/202301_star-map-R/). Also, the online shops creates a incorrect map sometimes, since for a given date these sites creates the map of a location at 22:00 UTC, that may not be night time at the given location (i.e. 22:00 UTC may be 11:00 AM in Auckland, NZ where the only visible star is the Sun obviously)

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

# Inputs
desired_place <- "Riyadh, Saudi Arabia"

# We are not using yet the timezone
desired_date <- make_datetime(
  year = 2023,
  month = 02,
  day = 14,
  hour = 22,
  min = 00
)

desired_date_tz <- force_tz(desired_date, "UTC")

# Spatial manipulation
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(s2)
library(nominatimlite)

## Wrange data and dates
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(lubridate)
library(lutz)

## Visualization
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfx)
library(ggshadow)
```

```r
load_celestial <- function(filename,
                           url = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/dieghernan/celestial_data@main/data/",
                           cachedir = tempdir()) {
  if (!dir.exists(cachedir)) {
    stop(
      "Please create ",
      path.expand(cachedir),
      " directory",
      "first"
    )
  }

  url <- file.path(url, filename)
  local_path <- file.path(cachedir, filename)


  if (!file.exists(local_path)) {
    download.file(url, local_path, mode = "wb", quiet = TRUE)
  }

  celestial <- sf::st_read(local_path, quiet = TRUE)

  return(celestial)
}

pretty_lonlat <- function(x, type, accuracy = 2) {
  positive <- x >= 0

  # Decompose
  x <- abs(x)
  D <- as.integer(x)
  m <- (x - D) * 60
  M <- as.integer(m)
  S <- round((m - M) * 60, accuracy)

  # Get label
  if (type == "lon") {
    lab <- ifelse(positive > 0, "E", "W")
  } else {
    lab <- ifelse(positive > 0, "N", "S")
  }


  # Compose
  label <- paste0(D, "\u00b0 ", M, "' ", S, '\" ', lab)
  return(label)
}


# Derive rotation degrees of the projection given a date and a longitude
get_mst <- function(dt, lng) {
  desired_date_utc <- lubridate::with_tz(dt, "UTC")


  yr <- lubridate::year(desired_date_utc)
  mo <- lubridate::month(desired_date_utc)
  dy <- lubridate::day(desired_date_utc)
  h <- lubridate::hour(desired_date_utc)
  m <- lubridate::minute(desired_date_utc)
  s <- lubridate::second(desired_date_utc)

  if ((mo == 1) || (mo == 2)) {
    yr <- yr - 1
    mo <- mo + 12
  }

  # Adjust times before Gregorian Calendar
  # See https://squarewidget.com/julian-day/
  if (lubridate::as_date(dt) > as.Date("1582-10-14")) {
    a <- floor(yr / 100)
    b <- 2 - a + floor(a / 4)
  } else {
    b <- 0
  }
  c <- floor(365.25 * yr)
  d <- floor(30.6001 * (mo + 1))

  # days since J2000.0
  jd <- b + c + d - 730550.5 + dy + (h + m / 60 + s / 3600) / 24
  jt <- jd / 36525

  # Rotation
  mst <- 280.46061837 + 360.98564736629 * jd +
    0.000387933 * jt^2 - jt^3 / 38710000.0 + lng

  # Modulo 360 degrees
  mst <- mst %% 360

  return(mst)
}
```

```r
# Cut a sf object with a buffer using spherical s2 geoms
# Optionally, project and flip

sf_spherical_cut <- function(x, the_buff, the_crs = sf::st_crs(x), flip = NULL) {
  # Get geometry type
  geomtype <- unique(gsub("MULTI", "", sf::st_geometry_type(x)))[1]

  # Keep the data frame, s2 drops it
  the_df <- sf::st_drop_geometry(x)
  the_geom <- sf::st_geometry(x)
  # Convert to s2 if needed
  if (!inherits(the_buff, "s2_geography")) {
    the_buff <- sf::st_as_s2(the_buff)
  }

  the_cut <- the_geom %>%
    # Cut with s2
    sf::st_as_s2() %>%
    s2::s2_intersection(the_buff) %>%
    # Back to sf and add the df
    sf::st_as_sfc() %>%
    sf::st_sf(the_df, geometry = .) %>%
    dplyr::filter(!sf::st_is_empty(.)) %>%
    sf::st_transform(crs = the_crs)

  # If it is not POINT filter by valid and non-empty
  # This if for performance
  if (!geomtype == "POINT") {
    # If any is GEOMETRYCOLLECTION extract the right value
    if (any(sf::st_geometry_type(the_cut) == "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION")) {
      the_cut <- the_cut %>%
        sf::st_collection_extract(type = geomtype, warn = FALSE)
    }

    the_cut <- the_cut %>%
      dplyr::filter(!is.na(sf::st_is_valid(.)))
  }

  if (!is.null(flip)) {
    the_cut <- the_cut %>%
      dplyr::mutate(geometry = geometry * flip) %>%
      sf::st_set_crs(the_crs)
  }

  return(the_cut)
}
```

```r
# Geocode place with nominatimlite
desired_place_geo <- geo_lite(desired_place, full_results = TRUE)

desired_place_geo %>%
  select(address, lat, lon)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   address                                                        lat   lon
#>   <chr>                                                        <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 الرياض, المالز, محافظة الرياض, منطقة الرياض, 11131, السعودية  24.6  46.7

# And get the coordinates
desired_loc <- desired_place_geo %>%
  select(lat, lon) %>%
  unlist()

desired_loc
#>      lat      lon 
#> 24.63892 46.71601
```

```r
# Get the rotation and prepare buffer and projection

# Get right degrees
lon_prj <- get_mst(desired_date_tz, desired_loc[2])
lat_prj <- desired_loc[1]

c(lon_prj, lat_prj)
#>       lon       lat 
#> 161.37934  24.63892

# Create proj4string w/ Airy projection

target_crs <- paste0("+proj=airy +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=", lon_prj, " +lat_0=", lat_prj)


target_crs
#> [1] "+proj=airy +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=161.379344231915 +lat_0=24.638916"

# We need to flip celestial objects to get the impression of see from the Earth
# to the sky, instead of from the sky to the Earth
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/75064359/7877917
# Flip matrix for affine transformation

flip_matrix <- matrix(c(-1, 0, 0, 1), 2, 2)


# And create an s2 buffer of the visible hemisphere at the given location
hemisphere_s2 <- s2_buffer_cells(
  as_s2_geography(
    paste0("POINT(", lon_prj, " ", lat_prj, ")")
  ),
  9800000,
  max_cells = 5000
)

# This one is for plotting
hemisphere_sf <- hemisphere_s2 %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_transform(crs = target_crs) %>%
  st_make_valid()
```

```r
mw <- load_celestial("mw.min.geojson")

# Add colors to MW to use on fill
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "yellow"))(5)
mw$fill <- factor(cols, levels = cols)


# And process it

# Cut to buffer
mw_end <- sf_spherical_cut(mw,
  the_buff = hemisphere_s2,
  # Change the crs
  the_crs = target_crs,
  flip = flip_matrix
)
```

```r
const <- load_celestial("constellations.lines.min.geojson")

# Cut to buffer

const_end <- sf_spherical_cut(const,
  the_buff = hemisphere_s2,
  # Change the crs
  the_crs = target_crs,
  flip = flip_matrix
)
```

```r
stars <- load_celestial("stars.6.min.geojson")


# Cut to buffer

stars_end <- sf_spherical_cut(stars,
  the_buff = hemisphere_s2,
  # Change the crs
  the_crs = target_crs,
  flip = flip_matrix
)
```

```r
grat <- st_graticule(
  ndiscr = 5000,
  lat = seq(-90, 90, 10),
  lon = seq(-180, 180, 30)
)

# Cut to buffer, we dont flip this one (it is not an object of the space)
grat_end <- sf_spherical_cut(
  x = grat,
  the_buff = hemisphere_s2,
  # Change the crs
  the_crs = target_crs
)
```

```r
lat_lab <- pretty_lonlat(desired_loc[1], type = "lat")
lon_lab <- pretty_lonlat(desired_loc[2], type = "lon")

pretty_labs <- paste(lat_lab, "/", lon_lab)

cat(pretty_labs)
#> 24° 38' 20.1" N / 46° 42' 57.64" E

# Create final caption to put on bottom

pretty_time <- paste(
  # Pretty Day
  scales::label_date(
    format = "%d %b %Y",
    locale = "en"
  )(desired_date_tz),
  # Pretty Hour
  format(desired_date_tz, format = "%H:%M", usetz = TRUE)
)

cat(pretty_time)
#> 14 Feb 2023 22:00 UTC

# Our final caption
caption <- toupper(paste0(
  "Star Map\n",
  desired_place, "\n",
  pretty_time, "\n",
  pretty_labs
))


cat(caption)
#> STAR MAP
#> RIYADH, SAUDI ARABIA
#> 14 FEB 2023 22:00 UTC
#> 24° 38' 20.1" N / 46° 42' 57.64" E
```

```r
# Prepare MULTILINESTRING

const_end_lines <- const_end %>%
  st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>%
  st_coordinates() %>%
  as.data.frame()


ggplot() +
  # Graticules
  geom_sf(data = grat_end, color = "grey60", linewidth = 0.25, alpha = 0.3) +
  # A blurry Milky Way
  with_blur(
    geom_sf(
      data = mw_end, aes(fill = fill), alpha = 0.1, color = NA,
      show.legend = FALSE
    ),
    sigma = 8
  ) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  # Glowing stars
  geom_glowpoint(
    data = stars_end, aes(
      alpha = br, size =
        br, geometry = geometry
    ),
    color = "white", show.legend = FALSE, stat = "sf_coordinates"
  ) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.05, 0.75)) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.1, 0.5)) +
  # Glowing constellations
  geom_glowpath(
    data = const_end_lines, aes(X, Y, group = interaction(L1, L2)),
    color = "white", size = 0.5, alpha = 0.8, shadowsize = 0.4, shadowalpha = 0.01,
    shadowcolor = "white", linejoin = "round", lineend = "round"
  ) +
  # Border of the sphere
  geom_sf(data = hemisphere_sf, fill = NA, color = "white", linewidth = 1.25) +
  # Caption
  labs(caption = caption) +
  # And end with theming
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(colour = "white"),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#191d29", color = "#191d29"),
    plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20),
    plot.caption = element_text(
      hjust = 0.5, face = "bold",
      size = rel(1),
      lineheight = rel(1.2),
      margin = margin(t = 40, b = 20)
    )
  )
#> Warning in CPL_transform(x, crs, aoi, pipeline, reverse, desired_accuracy, :
#> GDAL Error 1: PROJ: pipeline: Pipeline: A forward operation couldn't be
#> constructed
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>